# Calling Button Click Code from UserForm_QueryClose Does Not Work as Expected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that that reduces the Excel window size on `Workbook_Open` and launches a userform over it, which creates the illusion that it is acting as an application (rather than a spreadsheet) without the risk of hiding the application completely. When the userform closes, we must return the application window settings to a reasonable size.

This works in the current code when the user clicks Cancel, which maximizes the window and saves the changes, but when the same code is called from the `UserForm_QueryClose` it seems that `Application.WindowState = xlMaximize` does not trigger.

Here is the relevant code as written for both `UserForm_QueryClose` and `cmdCancel_Click`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    Call cmdCancel_Click
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Call Unload(Me)
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Close True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I know (having tried and succeeded) that replacing `Call cmdCancel_Click` with `Call MsgBox("Click 'Cancel'", vbOKOnly)` will force the right behaviour (because it forces the user through the Cancel button), but it is messier and requires an extra step for the user. For similar reasons I don't just want to turn off the X button (which I also succeeded in doing) because the user will not unexpect that feature to be turned off.

Any ideas why the `Application.WindowState` method is working (as expected) when clicking Cancel, but NOT when called from the QueryClose? Can this work as intended, or have I run afoul of some unavoidable inconsistency in how VBA handles such calls?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Cancel = True` line. It's preventing execution of the `If-Then` block.

Comment: Tried as you suggested. Behavior persists.  Attempted putting the `Application.WindowState` directly into the `UserForm_QueryClose` and this also fails whether `Cancel = True` or not.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I was able to duplicate the issue using your code, and fix it as described. I don't know what the difference would be. Good luck!